# Error while compiling, collect2: cannot find ld

Tags: c, gcc, ld

Could somebody have met this problem, I have  **collect2: cannot find 'ld'** error when try:

```
gcc -v -pthread -I /tmp/usr/include -no-use-gold-linker /tmp/teeest.c -o /tmp/teeest > /tmp/ok.log  2>/tmp/error.log
```

Output:

```
Using built-in specs.
gcc: unrecognized option '-no-use-gold-linker'
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-pthread' '-I' '/tmp/usr/include' '-no-use-gold-linker' '-o' '/tmp/teeest' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/cc1 -quiet -v -I /tmp/usr/include -iprefix ../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/ -D_REENTRANT /tmp/teeest.c -quiet -dumpbase teeest.c -mtune=generic -auxbase teeest -version -o /tmp/ccVr6ozd.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../lib/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /tmp/usr/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17), GMP version 4.3.1, MPFR version 2.4.1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: d2ae160e13b93f509f25a064aa53b455
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-pthread' '-I' '/tmp/usr/include' '-no-use-gold-linker' '-o' '/tmp/teeest' '-mtune=generic'
 as -V -Qy -o /tmp/ccCIoBhH.o /tmp/ccVr6ozd.s
GNU assembler version 2.20.51.0.2 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.20.51.0.2-5.44.el6 20100205
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/:../lib/../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:../lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-pthread' '-I' '/tmp/usr/include' '-no-use-gold-linker' '-o' '/tmp/teeest' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o /tmp/teeest /usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L../lib/../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L../lib /tmp/ccCIoBhH.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lpthread -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o /usr/lib/../lib64/crtn.o
collect2: cannot find 'ld'
```

Check ld existing:

```
ld: /usr/bin/ld /usr/share/man/man1/ld.1.gz
```

Check $PATH

```
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

I try to compile hello world application on C in /tmp dir.
CentOS 6, 2016, 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64, x86_64

Comment: Does it work without using that unknown option?

Comment: `-no-use-gold-linker` => `gcc: unrecognized option '-no-use-gold-linker'`. Your command line looks a little bit more complicated, than a "simple hello world" Why don't you try `gcc foo.c` first and see, what that brings to you?

Comment: because it's member's virtual machine at workspace. I have not root privileges, that's not factoring options, it's just for C-libraries. But question about ld binary..., option is unknown => not factoring, without option not work too.

Comment: hellow, 'gcc -v -I /tmp/usr/include /tmp/teeest.c -o /tmp/teeest > /tmp/ok.log  2>/tmp/error.log' give same result, -I option for include directory of standart libraries(thats for code, previously step, that's successfully) and next just - stdout & stderror. I tryed it.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. You don't need root privileges to execute `gcc` by itself. Just open up a terminal, go into your directory and type `gcc yourCode.c` (please make sure to actually use your sourcecode file instead of *'yourCode.c'*.

Comment: hellow, i need  -I /tmp/usr/include because there is libraries of stdio, for example. Standart gcc -i  /tmp/usr/include foo.cc give same result as in question.

Comment: First of, the libraries of stdio (e.g. the libc) should not be in a `/tmp` dir! It is temporary. It should be somehwhere in `/usr/lib`. Please do as I advised, create a new file, put `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { printf("Hello World\n"); return 0 }` in there and compile it with `gcc foo.c` and see, if that works or not. How do you solve a problem? Reduce the complexity to a minimum where it works and do some steps until it does not work anymore. Let's do that!

Comment: Currently code is '#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
printf("abc def");
return 0;
}', what's problem ?

Comment: Problem not in the code, in compiling process. It seen like file /usr/bin/ld doesnt exists, but it's exists correctly.

Comment: Copying include files in */tmp* is a bad idea. Your user has (should have) read permissions on */usr/include* where files are located by default, or you might have some *OS* or *gcc* installation problems. So, 1st get rid of this kind of junk. Then what's with `-no-use-gold-linker`? Check `which ld`'s output in terminal.

Comment: CristiFati, include - is not factoring position. -no-use-gold-linker - not recognized parameter (tryed resolve with it from Google), without it - same result.  WHICH LD: 'which: no ld in ((null))'

Comment: It looks as if your GCC setup/installation is broken.

Answer (score -1):

```
PATH=$PATH; export PATH; gcc -v -pthread -I /tmp/usr/include /tmp/test.c -o /tmp/test > /tmp/ok.log  2>/tmp/error.log; #eto pizdez
```

Comment: "*#eto pizdez*" :D. Regarding the answer: so you got rid of that funky argument, that should be it, because `PATH=$PATH` is absolutely useless.